# How much extra storage does MySQL fulltext index consume?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am looking for a way to estimate how much extra storage will be needed if a MySQL TEXT column gets a fulltext index.

Intuitively speaking the size of the fulltext index is dependent on the total length of text but what exactly is affecting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I have 200 MB of text data to index and the resulting index is 130 MB."

So it's comparable to the total size of data you index.

Comment: Over here the index size is 4 times smaller than the data it indexes. Apparently one parameter that affects index size is the amount of words separated by whitespace and the "ft_min_word_len" configuration property.

Comment: Just dropped a FULLTEXT index on a table with 1.4 million rows that had a 300MB index_length, and the new index_length is 220MB. All very relative, but easy to add one/drop one and see what difference it really makes to your table.